# Проблема с методом select у связных моделей

Tags: laravel

Есть проект на Laravel, прошу помощи для решения следующей проблемы:

Есть модель User

```
class User extends Model {
    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Есть модель Post

```
class Post extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Такой код работает без проблем:

```
$data = User::with(
            ['posts' => function($query) {
                $query->where('type', '2');
            }]
        )->first();
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но стоит мне добавить select для связной модели post, где указать только нужные поля и возвращается пустой объект.

```
$data = User::with(
            ['posts' => function($query) {
                $query->select('id', 'name')->where('type', '2');
            }]
        )->first();
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую laravel 5.7, и пробовал новый синтаксис:

```
$data = User::with(
            ['posts:id,name']
        )->first();
```

И все равно пустой объект.

Прошу подсказать, что я делаю не так? Очень нужно получить у связных моделей, только определенный набор полей.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил. На всякий случай отвечу на свой же вопрос, вдруг кому пригодиться.

При построении запроса в нативном slq, для связной таблицы не обязательно выбирать для отображение в выборке поле внешнего ключа. Главное чтобы он фигурировал в условии where.
Но в Laravel данное правильно не работает. Если в метод select связно модели указать нужные поля, но не указать внешний ключ, вернется пустая коллекция связных элементов.

В моем случае корректный код выглядел следующим образом:

```
$data = User::with(
            ['posts' => function($query) {
                $query->select('id', 'user_id', 'name')->where('type', '2');
            }]
        )->first();
```